# How to query with or? spring data mongodb datatables

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, datatables, spring-data-mongodb

I am using the spring-data-mongodb-datatables repository for my datatables and I am trying to make a backend or query that takes 3 criteria's and searches for them in my DB with an or search meaning if any of the 3 criterias match a row then it will be shown. This is the repository I am using: https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-mongodb-datatables . Below I have pasted my code a long with the orOperator declaration for more context. Does anyone know why it is not working or have any solutions to this problem?

```
Criteria one = where("taskOther").exists(true).ne("");
Criteria two = where("taskWhyNotComment").exists(true).ne("");
Criteria three = where("taskImproveComment").exists(true).ne("");
Criteria allWithOr = one.orOperator(two,three);
input.getColumn("taskOther").get().getSearch().setValue("");
return topTaskRepository.findAll(input, allWithOr);
```

```
/**
     * Creates an 'or' criteria using the $or operator for all of the provided criteria
     * <p>
     * Note that mongodb doesn't support an $or operator to be wrapped in a $not operator.
     * <p>
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@link #orOperator(Criteria...)} follows a not() call directly.
     * @param criteria
     */
    public Criteria orOperator(Criteria... criteria) {
        BasicDBList bsonList = createCriteriaList(criteria);
        return registerCriteriaChainElement(new Criteria("$or").is(bsonList));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in case someone in the future is wondering the same thing. Turns out this is how you have to chain the orOperator. You cannot just call it on an already created criteria.

```
return repository.findAll(input, new Criteria().orOperator(
                    Criteria.where("taskOther").exists(true).ne(""),
                    Criteria.where("taskWhyNotComment").exists(true).ne(""),
                    Criteria.where("taskImproveComment").exists(true).ne("")));
```